# Leaflet slider show date time below with the slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet

The query is continued from the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475066/leaflet-time-slider-issue-for-a-beginner). I wanted to know how can I get the time to show like in this demo example [here](http://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/). In this example, as you slide you can view the date time as well. Currently I'm unable to view so.

Below is my code:

```
html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="map">
</div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/SliderControl.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>

js

var map = L.map('map').setView([40.7241745, -73.9841674], 11);

L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
maxZoom: 16
}).addTo(map);

var myData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.0481651,40.7208714]},"properties":{"endDate":"2014-12-11 22:00:00","startDate":"2014-12-08 20:00:00"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.9924459,40.7176705]},"properties":{"endDate":"2014-12-21 20:00:00","startDate":"2014-12-01 11:00:00"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.4557279,40.6790963]},"properties":{"endDate":"2014-12-08 20:00:00", "startDate":"2014-12-08 19:00:00"}}]}

var mylayer = L.geoJson(myData).addTo(map);
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({position: "topright", layer: mylayer});
map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();
$('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.startDate.substr(0, 19));
// only change I made was use startDate instead of default time as startDate is a column in my feature set.

css

div#map {
 height: 600px;
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 20px;
 border-color: #000000;
 z-index: 0;
}

body {
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says: "Adjust the used time property so that it fits your project". What they actually mean with that is that you have to edit the sourcecode of the actual plugin. If you look at line 90 and 91 of [LeafletSlider.js](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js#L90):

```
if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time){
    if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 19));
```

In your case you would need to change those to this:

```
if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.startDate){
    if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.startDate.substr(0, 19));
```

Check this working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K5nd6eZAfDfkfyEXHgMI?p=preview